# Unable to create user after deleting database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been learning MVC and got to this part:

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };

        UserManager.Delete(user);

        //myDBLoginDetails ent = new myDBLoginDetails();
        //ent.uspInsertUser(user.UserName, model.Password, model.FirstName, model.LastName, user.Email);

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
          await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

          // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
          // Send an email with this link
          // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
          // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
          // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
     }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

I thought everything was going smoothly and I successfully registered\saved users to the SQL Server db (no MDF file).  To continue testing and such I remmed out the code to register\insert the users and deleted the table and recreated it so I could eventually start from scratch.
But then when I tried to re-register a user so I could step through the code to learn what all is going on I discovered my user(s) are still on my PC as I got the messages:

> Name tempUser is already taken.
>
> Email 'tempUser@email.com' is already taken.

I tried to delete the user (using UserManager.Delete(user);) but got the message:

> [InvalidOperationException: The object cannot be deleted because it
>   was not found in the ObjectStateManager.]

I searched for an explanation and resolution but have failed, and only discovered there may be other\better ways to register\edit\delete users and frustration eventually set in.

So, I guess I need a couple things solved.  I have a LoginDetalsEDmodel.edmx so am I still correct to use a Stored Proc or do I use the Framework?  If the Framework then how do I do that?

And.... how do I get rid of the user(s) that are still on my computer (which are gone from the DB)?

I hope I explained this well enough as I'm still learning......

Comment: @TitltingCode The 'user' you are trying to delete with UserManager.DeleteUser doesn't exist, which is why you are receiving that message. If you want to delete an existing user, you must first get that ApplicationUser object with UserManager.FindByEmailAsync("tempUser@email.com") and pass this object to UsertManager.DeleteUser

Comment: That deleted the user! Thanks!